# Configure HAProxy 2.2 with HA PostgreSQL Cluster with Docker (Zalando Spilo)

Tags: haproxy

I was successfully using [Spilo](https://github.com/zalando/spilo) (HA PostgreSQL Cluster with Docker) in Docker Swarm behind HAProxy. I used one of the [HAProxy configuration](https://github.com/zalando/spilo/issues/379#issuecomment-647481576) posted by one of the users.
It was working fine for HAProxy 2.1. I updated HAProxy to 2.2 and suddenly it doesn't work anymore. In the announce of HAProxy 2.2 I found that there was some changes for the [Health Checks](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/announcing-haproxy-2-2/#health-check-overhaul).

This is my backend section of the master that was working before:

```
backend backend_master
    option httpchk OPTIONS /master
    server dbnode1 spilo1:5432 maxconn 100 check port 8008 resolvers docker_resolver resolve-prefer ipv4
    server dbnode2 spilo2:5432 maxconn 100 check port 8008 resolvers docker_resolver resolve-prefer ipv4
    server dbnode3 spilo3:5432 maxconn 100 check port 8008 resolvers docker_resolver resolve-prefer ipv4
```

After reading HAProxy 2.2 documentation I'm not sure why the current configuration doesn't work anymore.

This is the message from the logs:

```
Server be-postgres-master/dbnode1 is DOWN, reason: Layer7 invalid response, info: "TCPCHK got an empty response at step 1", check duration: 5ms. 2 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue. 
Server be-postgres-master/dbnode2 is DOWN, reason: Layer7 invalid response, info: "TCPCHK got an empty response at step 1", check duration: 4ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
Server be-postgres-master/dbnode3 is DOWN, reason: Layer7 invalid response, info: "TCPCHK got an empty response at step 1", check duration: 4ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[ALERT] 235/144508 (6) : backend 'be-postgres-master' has no server available!
```

I downgraded HAProxy to 2.1 and it works again but how to make it work with 2.2 ?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know whether you're still struggling with the issue or not, but changing the request method from `OPTIONS` to `GET` in the `httpchk` section helped me.